# CentOS 6.4 as VirtualBox guest under Windows 8 host, fullscreen mode causes unresponsive cursor

Tags: centos, windows, virtualbox

I apologize in advance if this is an inappropriate place to post this question.

I've installed VirtualBox 4.1.26 in Windows 8 6.2 (I don't think I have Pro) and got CentOS 6.4 installed with Guest Additions.  When I enter fullscreen mode, I can still move the cursor around the guest screen, but no clicks are registered.  Works normally when I exit fullscreen.    Anyone point me in the right direction to correct this (or tell me where I should be posting this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These issues sound related to your problem:

- [Can't get full screen Centos-64 guest - vista 64 host](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=19149)
- [Help with virtualbox](http://centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?viewmode=flat&order=ASC&topic_id=12724&forum=37)

In these they're saying that your xorg.conf file should not include any specific display settings for the screen resolution. I would experiment with adding/removing a line like this in my xorg.conf to confirm:

```
Modes   "1280x1024" "1024x768" "800x600"
```

Additionally I would double check your setup steps with the ones outlined in this post:

- [VirtualBox Guest Additions on Fedora 18/17, CentOS/RHEL 6.4/5.9](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

#### general steps

```
mkdir /media/VirtualBoxGuestAdditions
mount -r /dev/cdrom /media/VirtualBoxGuestAdditions
yum update kernel*
reboot
yum install gcc kernel-devel kernel-headers dkms make bzip2
```

Then set this variable:

```
## Current running kernel on Fedora, CentOS 6 and Red Hat (RHEL) 6 ##
KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/`uname -r`

## Export KERN_DIR ##
export KERN_DIR
```

Install guest additions:

```
cd /media/VirtualBoxGuestAdditions

# 32-bit and 64-bit systems run following
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Comment: I will try these today and report back.  Thanks in the meantime.

Comment: Following these steps worked "perfectly".  It solved my initial problem, therefore I thank you!  Now I need to resolve why the CentOS guest takes 2 minutes to boot, and is incredibly laggy once it does.

Comment: That's most likely due to the CPU settings not being configured correctly in the VM's settings. Make sure **Intel VT-x** and **AMD-V** settings are ON. They're under the Processor section of the VM settings.

Answer (score 0):

Did you **install** the guest additions?
How much video memory have you set for the display? 3D acceleration enabled?

What does /usr/share/xresprobe/xorg.conf show?

Comment: Please don't post follow-up questions in answers. Use the comments below if you need clarification. [How to Answer a Question Guide](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer).